# How to create own code completion description in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

For example in my user model I have a computed property `fullName`:

```
var fullName: String {
    return firstName + " " + lastName
}
```

I want to set a short description for this variable so that during Code Completion I have a  small hint.

Like in the screen below:

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precede the variable declaration with a three-slash comment. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `/** */` to add document to your code

```
/** Here is fullname */
var fullName: String {
  return firstName + " " + lastName
}
```